# Изменить текст в блоке div

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

есть блок:

```
"div class="t744__price-currency">$</div"
```

Нужно с помощью jquery удалить $ в блоке и поменять на руб..

Answer (score 3):

```js
var $divCurrency = $(".t744__price-currency");
$divCurrency.text($divCurrency.text().replace("$", "руб."));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="t744__price-currency">$</div>
```